# getting error "Error: ENOTDIR: not a directory, access " in my next js page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

When I make new page called as ***`AboutPage.js`*** inside ***`pages`*** folder then I get some error in terminal and on my UI on my ***`NEXT JS app`*** when I try to access that page.

The ERROR is:

```
error - Error: ENOTDIR: not a directory, access '/mnt/BEAA30A3AA305A5B/KevalActivity/Skills/Programming/Builds/JavaScript/Next JS/instagram-clone/pages/AboutPage.js/index.tsx'
```

and I am attaching the error image.

[image: Error preview in my browser]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is not how you are supposed to declare new pages with Nextjs.

I refer you to this documentation about the routing system : https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/introduction

You should only have an AboutPage.js file in your pages directory, and then access it with url localhost:3000/aboutpage .

Comment: yeah it was totally right

Comment: I want to tick the answer but it is telling you can do it after 5 min

Answer (score 0):

You are `fetch or query or ...` to a file in a wrong way. In React, Next and ... you have to remove `.js` from `fetch` address.

As "Bloodbee" said: `about.js` => `/about`

And

> const response = await fetch("/api/upload.js", {  ... });

=>

> const response = await fetch("/api/upload", {  ... });

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when i was learning next js. My mistake was I used `<Link href="/posts/first-post.js">this page!</Link>` instead of `<Link href="/posts/first-post">this page!</Link>`. I used the file extension ".js" in href which is not the way to do it.